# I want my old speed dial page on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I know this has been posted alot around here. But this is about the new google update after I tried to install google chrome on a new laptop. Google Chrome Version 29.0.1547.76 m has ruined the speed dial look I once had. It now shows a search input box and a smaller set of speed dials below it. (see image please)

[image]

Is there a way to get back the nice clean speed dial page we all love?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

- enter `chrome://flags` in the address bar
- goto `Enable Instant Extended API`
- Set it to `Disabled`
- Restart Chrome

This worked for me (until Google decides otherwise).

**Edit**: If you go directly to `chrome://flags/#enable-instant-extended-api` you don't have to search :)