# How do I change the new tab page in chrome 29?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

*I have already researched this and all information is either for old versions of chrome or says that it's impossible.*

*Also, I don't want to attach any arguments to the end of chrome, like suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/8737/how-do-i-fix-google-chromes-latest-new-tab-page)*

With the new tab page in chrome `29.0.1547.62`, the first launch (as in, every time you launch a new chrome window when none are open) is always *very* laggy. It can take up to 1-2 minutes and sometimes crashes.

I use the omnibox if I want to search, I have no need for the google search bar (it's easier to use, you just press <kbd>F6</kbd> and type your search) and I don't need the most visited pages.

What do I do in the newest chrome to change this?  I'm using windows 7 and the desktop version of windows 8 (two different computers)

Comment: One option is to revert to the old new tab page as described [here](http://superuser.com/questions/8737/how-do-i-fix-google-chromes-latest-new-tab-page?rq=1). And, of course, file a bug report.

Comment: I don't want to add any arguments to chrome on launch, I want to do it within chrome.

Comment: Maybe you could try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/651869/i-want-my-old-speed-dial-page-on-google-chrome/651870#651870) and set a blanc homepage.

Comment: That may or may not be possible. Not every option is available for changing within the application. Searching through the `chrome://flags` page reveals nothing related (unless its some rendering bug; might want to try disabling all the rendering options there and seeing if it helps). Since you're asking here, I'm assuming you've already attempted changing the default startup page in `chrome://settings`.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/650099/restore-new-tab-page-behavior-in-google-chrome-29-0-1547-76-to-link-to-apps

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, type in `chrome://flags/#enable-instant-extended-api` and disable that option to remove the Google Search Bar from the New Tab Page.